# Wait for the second VBScript script until ended from primary VBScript script

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript script that runs a second VBScript script. The second VBScript script asks some questions from the input box. My problem is that “MyShell.Run” does not wait until SecondVBscript.vbs has ended. And the other VBScript syntax run immodestly also

I need to wait for the MyShell.Run process to end and then perform the other VBScript syntax. How can I do that?

```
Set MyShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

MyShell.Run " C:\Program Files\SecondVBscript.vbs"

Set MyShell = Nothing
```

Other VBScript syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Run` method has an optional argument `bWaitOnReturn`, if you set that to true, won't it wait then?
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28VS.85%29.aspx) for the documentation of the `Run` command.

Comment: please give me relevant example in order to put it in the script
thx
yael

Comment: @yael: From the documentation page `Return = WshShell.Run("notepad " & WScript.ScriptFullName, 1, true)`.

Comment: I don’t understand the notepad in the syntax
yael

Comment: @yael: It's part of a sample that will open notepad. For you it should probably be like `MyShell.Run ("C:\Program Files\SecondVBscript.vbs", 1, true)`.

Answer (score -1):

If I get you correctly, you can make your script wait at certain point using `sleep` method of WScript object:

```
MyShell.Sleep(12000)
```

Comment: sorry but its not agood solution , I must to wait until script ended
and then cont

Comment: @yael: Script ends only when vbs parser reads the last line of the script. You can decide for yourself now :)