# wait for the second VB script untill ended from primary VB script

Tags: vbscript

Hi I have VB script that run second VB script The second VB script ask some questions from the input box My problem is that “MyShell.Run” not wait until SecondVBscript.vbs will ended And the Other VB syntax run immodestly also

Need to wait for MyShell.Run process ended and then perform the Other VB syntax How can I do that?

```
Set MyShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

MyShell.Run " C:\Program Files\SecondVBscript.vbs" 

Set MyShell = Nothing
```

Other VB syntax

Comment: You could have the first script create a file, and the second one erase it, and just keep checking in the first if the file is still there, perhaps

Comment: this is better suited to Stack Overflow. it will be migrated automatically.  you will need to register accounts here and on Stack Overflow (with the same OpenID) to regain ownership of the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [wait for the second VB script untill ended from primary VB script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031420/wait-for-the-second-vb-script-untill-ended-from-primary-vb-script)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Exec](http://ss64.com/wsh/exec.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an additional argument --

```
MyShell.Run "C:\Program Files\SecondVBscript.vbs", 1, true
```

Already answered @ [Wait for the second VBScript script until ended from primary VBScript script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031420/wait-for-the-second-vb-script-untill-ended-from-primary-vb-script)